# Dynamically create table row when cell reach certain limit

Tags: php, arrays, loops, html-table

Please I want to create a table using PHP, but I found it difficult to dynamically add new `TABLE ROW`
when the looped `CELL` is already 4.

Example: The below code will give me this:

```
<table>
<td>CELL1</td><td>CELL2</td><td>CELL3</td><td>CELL4 </td><td>CELL5</td><td>CELL6</td><td>CELL7</td><td>CELL8</td>
</table>
```

But I want once the cell is 4 it will create a new row for other items

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>CELL1</td><td>CELL2</td><td>CELL3</td><td>CELL4 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CELL5</td><td>CELL6</td><td>CELL7</td><td>CELL8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My Sample Code

```
<?php
$string = 'wifi,pool,cafe,lunch, item1,item2,item3,item4,item5';
$tdlimit = 4;
$converArry = explode(',', $string);
$AddTable = '<table>';
foreach($converArry as $tds){
    //if(count_of_cell_is_4_create_tr){$AddTable .= '<tr>';}
    $AddTable .= '<td>'.$tds.'</td>';
    //if(count_of_cell_is_4_create_tr){$AddTable .= '</tr>';}
}
$AddTable .= '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create rows like this, you don't just need to check if it's already four. You need to check if it's *divisible by* four. If you don't do that, then you'll get four items in the first row, and however many are left in the second row, even if that's more than four. So you need some logic to determine when to start new rows.

You can do this by accessing the index of your array and checking if there's any remainder when dividing it by four.

```
<?php
$string = 'wifi,pool,cafe,lunch, item1,item2,item3,item4,item5';
$tdlimit = 4;
$converArry = explode(',', $string);

// open a row at the beginning
$AddTable = '<table><tr>';
foreach ($converArry as $i => $tds) {  // add the array index to your loop definition

    // if the index is a multiple of four, close the current row and open a new one
    if ($i && ($i % 4 == 0)) $AddTable .= '</tr><tr>';
    $AddTable .= '<td>'.$tds.'</td>';
}

// in case the total count of items is a multiple of four, close the last row
if (($i + 1) % 4 == 0) $AddTable .= '</tr>';

$AddTable .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, I didn't tried it yet.

```
$string = 'wifi,pool,cafe,lunch, item1,item2,item3,item4,item5';
$tdlimit = 0;
$converArry = explode(',', $string);
$AddTable = '<table>';
$AddTable = '<tr>';
foreach($converArry as $tds){
    if($tdlimit%4 == 0){
        $AddTable .='</tr>';
        $AddTable .='<tr>';
    }
    $AddTable .= '<td>'.$tds.'</td>';
    $tdlimit++;
}

$AddTable .='</tr>'
$AddTable .= '<table>';
```

Comment: It worked, but when the items are 9 in number it create 4 cell in the first row and 5 in the second row

Comment: This is the out put of the code, can it create additional row for the last item5 since i want the cell to be 4 `<table><tbody><tr><td>wifi</td><td>pool</td><td>cafe</td><td>lunch</td></tr><tr><td> item1</td><td>item2</td><td>item3</td><td>item4</td><td>item5</td></tr></tbody></table>`

Comment: it worked i like your answer because is very simple to understand